# Slow Graph Creation in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I've copied in what I believe is the problematic section of code. To summarise the sheet I've got two buttons, one to import the data and process it in a table, then a second to create a graphical representation of the data. But every time I press it my excel goes into not responding mode but does eventually create the graph. The data itself isn't complex, literally a number with maybe a couple decimals attached. I have variations of this sheet for different uses all of which hold this problem to a varying degree.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as its slowing down our processes.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim cht As ChartObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("data").Activate

Set cht = Sheets("data").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=624, Top:=250, Height:=405)

cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("data").Range("C5:AH27")
cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I've tried doing something with just the raw copied data and a different sheet completely and it seems to work fine, I then transfer these changes onto the original doc and the issues pursues.

Comment: Do you have any event handling code in the Workbook (or in any loaded Excel AddIns) that could be being triggered by your code? You could try switching events off at the start of your Sub and back on at the end with `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = True`

Comment: There's nothing in this code that would make it slow.

Comment: I've just tried the switching the events on and off, it's improved it but its still slow, I can attach the entire code if that would help, I am by no means a programmer by trade so I might have missed something.